# identifier error when declaring object array for file

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static Vehicle[] fillArray(inputString) throws exception { 
    while(readRecords.ready()) {
       Vehicle newVehicle; 
       checkType = readRecords.readLine(); 
       if(checkType.equals("vehicle")) { 
            String ownersName = readRecords.readLine(); 
            String address = readRecords.readLine(); 
            String phone = readRecords.readLine(); 
            String email = readRecords.readline(); 
            newVehicle = new Vehicle(ownersName,address,phone,email); 
            list.add(newVehicle); 
       }
```

I am getting an `<identifier> expected error`. Signals at the inputString within the parenthesis.

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the code surrounding all of this? `Exception` should be capitalized.

Comment: identifier expected error

Comment: You must have a type for each input parameter.  Put a type before `inputString`, within the `()`s.

Comment: @Rickie *I know*. I need to see the code that *caused* the error as I am obviously *not* psychic.

Comment: 2 things, `inputString` must be supported by declaring its datatype and `exception` should actually be titlecased if you're using Java's `Exception`

Comment: @Rickie Please edit your post. It's next-to-impossible to read in a comment. Imagine if you had to read the sample you just posted.

Comment: @Rickie, comments are used for clarifying your intent, mostly not for /more/ code. In that case, you can always edit your question to add more code. And, welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks. I capitalized Exception and added a datatype which i believe fixed the error. However, it gave me a bunch more. So I will go work on that now!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell what type the parameter is:

```
public static Vehicle[] fillArray(String inputString) throws Exception
```

Otherwise the compiler doesn't know if `inputString` is a string, an int, or some other object. It won't guess by the name.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a type for your parameter. Try this :

```
public static Vehicle[] fillArray(String inputString) throws exception
```